# Need help adding a column to table in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, addition

I have spent the day reading through various articles, but I can't seem to find an answer to my problem.  Months ago, I created an app in android studio that uses SQLite. Now, I have gotten to the point that I need to add a column to the table.  I am able to add the column in the adapter class with no problem, but I am having a problem in the 'MainActivity.class'.  The code is as follows...

```
    private void setData() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
                    dbAdapter.insertSpace(String.valueOf(i+1),"Confined Space " + (i+1),"description "+(i+1),"","","","","","","","","","",
                           "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",
                            "","","","");
                }

                try {
                    // Execute insert function
                } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error inserting record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
           }
        }).start();

    }
}

and the error message I am getting is...


    error: method insertSpace in class DBAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
    required: String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String
    found: String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length



My required content shows 34 columns, and found is 33.  What do I need to do to make these equal, and where do I need to make the adjustments?  I added a column once before, but just can't remember how I did it :(
```

Comment: Can you provide the insertSpace() implementation.

Comment: Sorry Swayangjit...  I was able to fix the issue.  It turns out that I had overlooked an activity and had not made the necessary changes.   I was focusing on mt DBAdapter, but needed to make changes to my update activity, as well as my View activity.    Thank you for your response however :)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry all.  This was entirely my own mess-up.  I had only changed the structure of the add query...  I had neglected to make the same changes to my update, and my listview.  Every call to the database in the app needed to be edited, not jus.t the add record